# Maven issue with spring-data-neo4j

Tags: spring, maven, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

The spring-data-neo4j artifact is causing access denied warnings to the tinkerpop domain when fetching resources.

My pom.xml file has the following relevant dependencies:

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
```

When running maven, I receive the following errors (just providing the first few rows):

```
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom
Downloading: http://go-build.local/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded: http://go-build.local/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom (8 KB at 17.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j-parent/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-parent-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom
Downloading: http://go-build.local/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j-parent/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-parent-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded: http://go-build.local/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j-parent/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-parent-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom (27 KB at 42.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-parent:3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-asm:3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-parent:3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-parent:3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

etc. etc.

I have tried several things without much luck such as:

- Adding exclusions for the 3 tinkerpop items listed in the spring-data-neo4j pom to the dependency
- Adding dependencies of the requested spring libraries (e.g. spring-beans, spring-tx, etc.)
- Adding repositories for springframework.org

There is no reference to any repo (including tinkerpop) in any of my pom files or maven settings except when I tried to include references to neo4j or springsource's repos directly to try and debug this issue.

Below is a stripped down version of the pom.xml and settings.xml files that still exhibit the same behavior:

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
           <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<settings>
   <localRepository>/Users/ian/.m2/repository</localRepository>
</settings>
```

Comment: you sure it is not a networking issue or so? Also, the tinkerpop repo is not longer in use, everything should be in maven central nowadays.

Comment: I am not referring to tinkerpop at all as a repo in my configuration. I didn't even know it existed until this issue occurred.I am only using central except for my attempts to use neo4j and springsource's repos directly. Not sure if there is a downstream reference to tinkerpop as maven is trying to pull down the dependencies for the spring-data-neo4j artifact.

Comment: Can you show the complete pom.xml file? Furthermore have you configured some repos in settings.xml file?

Comment: I ran a test with a stripped down pom.xml and settings.xml and still produced the same result. I have posted them to the bottom of my question.

Comment: What I can see there are only warnings, not errors, does something not work in the end? I think the tinkerpop maven repository was moved at some point. Please update to Spring Data Neo4j 2.1.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Michael, it works in the end but is annoying to see. I will upgrade to 2.1 but will need to address some changes in the neo4j codebase such as Neo4jTemplate.beginTx() now undefined as is SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

Comment: SpringJunit4ClassRunner is a spring-test dependency, you can just add that to your project won't be exported by SDN as it is test-code.

Comment: and `beginTx()` can be done by using TransactionTemplate but you should rather use `@Transactional`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add mirror for all repositories, this will avoid to reach repositories pointed in lib pom.

```
<mirror>
  <id>all</id>
  <name>all</name>
  <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Comment: Just need "tinkerpop-repository" instead of * in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to reach a unusual maven repository instead of [maven central](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/), cause the artifacts for [sping and neo4 are in maven central available](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspring-data-neo4j). And furthermore the problem which causes the problems is of course:

```
..rom/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/s...
```

Comment: spring data neo4j is NOT in the tinkerpop maven repos, refer to http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j#maven for details.

Comment: Not referencing tinkerpop anywhere. Not sure where this is coming from. If I remove this dependency the problem goes away:
            `<dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>`

Comment: Maybe this is an issue in spring-data-neo4j and the repo is referenced there and needs to be removed, could you open an issue if you can verify it?

Comment: Where should I open the ticket? The SpringSource JIRA doesn't appear to have the neo4j project listed anywhere.